# Will there be a problem if I have my maiden name in the petition, but married name in all other documents?

Tags: usa

My case is currently open at the embassy,I am female and I was married when the petition was filed. My brother is my petitioner and I am basically the beneficiary of USA Visa Category F4. In the petition, my name is written that of before marriage (maiden name), but in all other documents like Marriage Certificate,Passport,National ID card of current country(Pakistan) are based on my married name.

Would there be a problem during visa interview or at any stage because of different surnames? Maiden name is used only in form I-130(which is only a application form)

Comment: If you were married when the petition was filed, and all your documents were in your marrried name, why did you file in your maiden name?

Comment: A marriage certificate is usually sufficient to establish a name change due to marriage.  But you may indeed be asked (as @Traveller has asked) about the reasons for using your maiden name when the petition was submitted after you were married.  If they do ask, any reasonable explanation will probably be fine, so just tell the truth.